# What can we do to improve the top 10 most viewed questions?

Tags: discussion

I was browsing the [data explorer](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/937/useful-data-stackexchange-com-queries-for-regular-users-of-the-site) and noticed some highly viewed posts that could use some editing and improvement. Here are the top 10 most viewed questions:

[image]

In particular I would like to see some questions/answers improved for the following:

- [What are the optimal JPEG settings for high-resolution Facebook photos?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/27709/what-are-the-optimal-jpeg-settings-for-high-resolution-facebook-photos)
- [How does 18 megapixels compare to 12 megapixels?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9886/how-does-18-megapixels-compare-to-12-megapixels)
- [How to reduce the file size of my photos (to under 15 MB)?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11638/how-to-reduce-the-file-size-of-my-photos-to-under-15-mb)

Potentially they already have great answers but are buried below the highest voted answers. Maybe just some additional visibility from the experts in Meta will help this part out. If anyone is feeling adventurous and wants to improve our most viewed content, give it a shot!

I also think some of the questions themselves would benefit from broader generalization to appeal to more users, especially since they are so highly viewed.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up! I guess a lot of the time, this would just be a matter of existing members taking a closer look, and carefully choosing which answers to vote up. As you said, there are some good answers, but the votes kind of support answers that maybe aren't the best. If some of these answers are edited, that gives people a window of opportunity to change their vote...i.e. unselect (remove, but not down vote) votes, to allow better answers to float to the top.

Comment: something like this http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/715/lets-get-critical-nov-2013-site-self-evaluation?cb=1

Comment: I think the 12-18mpix one is getting so many hits precisely because people were searching for something specific and found that. I tried to generalize that one already with [Do megapixels matter with modern sensor technology?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14773/do-megapixels-matter-with-modern-sensor-technology) a couple of years ago, with moderate success.

Comment: @mattdm - How would you feel about someone editing the top answer to the 12 vs 18mpix question to link to your more generalized question? How else could we direct users to it?

Comment: @dpollitt Well, we could mark that one as a duplicate of the more general one... that would make sense as "12 vs 18" becomes more and more obsolete as a precise search. Although probably we will get it again as phone cameras get into that range. Adding a little block at the top of the question without closing it is an interesting experiment to try.

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be done through  [**Site Self-Evaluation review queue**](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/715/lets-get-critical-nov-2013-site-self-evaluation?cb=1), like they did, we can also evaluate them and then improve the posts that need more improvements votes.

ASFAIK this is the best method to improve the posts and also I did not see any other way among all other Stack exchange sites.